# Trying to optimize this code. Speed problems

Tags: r

This code gives me exactly what I want, but it gets really slow with larger datasets. Would greatly appreciate some insights on how I can do the same thing with more speed.

```
df = data.frame(v1 = runif(1:15000), v2 = runif(1:15000))

rolling.monthlies = lapply(df, function(x){
  p = sapply(1:length(x), function(i){
    m = rev(x[1:i])
    m = m[seq(1,length(m),21)]
    m = rev(m)
  })
  return(p)
})
```

Comment: Can you add explanation what the code is doing?

Comment: Ultimate solution - rewrite time critical code to C++ with [Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).

Comment: It's for price time series. I'm approximating monthly data to be measured each day. I have other applications for it as well but the crux is that I need to spit out a rolling list of data that gets sequentially bigger as the time series progresses and remeasured at each observation.

Comment: you will need to reduce your problem to something reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

We can eliminate the two `rev` calls by using `seq` like this.  We can also use `lapply` in place of `sapply` since no simplification is done saving the attempt:

```
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
df = data.frame(v1 = runif(1:15000), v2 = runif(1:15000)) # input

rolling.monthlies2 = lapply(df, function(x)
  lapply( seq_along(x), function(i) x[seq(i %% 29, i, 29)] )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect and so much faster! Am I correct in assuming that, using the modulo %% operator, it's making the vector going in perfectly divisible by the sequence length?

Seems like there's so many more applications to this now that I think about it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes.  `seq(i %% 29, i, 29)` ends at `i` exactly since `i - i%%29` is divisible by 29.